# Golang - Scan strings with multiple complicated regex patterns

Tags: regex, go

I am trying golang's `regexp` library to test regular expressions. Basically, my goal is to scan a a given list of filenames with a given list of regex patterns. I am doing this to see if filenames match a specific pattern (files with only 1 letter or digit/files with no extension etc.)

I looked into `regexp` library and and noticed that `Compile` function can only take 1 pattern and only return 1 `regexp` object. This wouldn't work in my case, since I have a list of multiple patterns.

There's also `MatchString` function which I can use to scan one filename at a time with a given pattern. But like the documentation states, it doesn't support complicated patterns.

Is there any way I can supply my list of regex patterns in the beginning of the code and get a `regexp` object back which I can use to scan my list of filenames throughout the program?

Comment: Do you mean you need a regex that matches either one pattern or another? `A|B|C|...|N`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have 2 lists: "patterns.txt" and "filenames.txt". I want to scan every filename in the second list with the regex patterns that's presented in the first list. Are you suggesting I should concatenate every pattern in the second list into a one giant string of regex pattern and then use that one regex pattern to scan the second list?

Comment: It depends on what kind of regexps they are. I used this approach in one of my Python scripts, and it works well. Without any more details, it is hard to advise though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For example one of the regex patterns look like this: (temp|startup|WINNT|Windows|[Ss]ystem32)\\out[0-9]{5,22}.exe|dll$. Although this one is not a complicated pattern, it is just an example of what kind of regexp patterns I have. As you can imagine concatenating a few hundreds of patterns like this into a one string wouldn't be optimal. That's why I asked for an alternative solution.

Comment: Ok, as they are not matching the whole string, you really should not OR them.

Comment: So I guess there's no better way to do this. I'll just have to scan one filename at a time with `MatchString` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some inherent reason that you have to use Go to solve this problem, Go is pretty terrible when it comes to regex. See: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26623

In the past when I've absolutely needed to do regex, I would set up some kind of server using Perl or PyPy that can be hit via some kind of endpoint when I needed to process and use regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to make your own regex function using the existent ones, something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    listOfPatterns := []string{"pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"}
    listOfFilenames := []string{"nopattern01.txt", "ispattern1.txt", "nopattern01.txt", "ispattern2"}

    fmt.Println(CheckPatternList(listOfPatterns, listOfFilenames))
}

func CheckPatternList(listOfPatterns []string, listOfFilenames []string) []string {
    matchedElements := []string{}
    for _, element := range listOfFilenames {
        for _, regex := range listOfPatterns {
            didMatched, err := regexp.MatchString(regex, element)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            if didMatched == true {
                matchedElements = append(matchedElements, element)

            }
        }
    }
    return matchedElements
}
```

[Run Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/DaBtY5g8hgQ)